# What POJO, DTO, Entity and other such components called?

Tags: java, spring, components, dto, pojo

I am searching for a keyword which defines POJO, Entities, Controllers and other components all together?

As I wanted to know about all of them, I was searching for a site, so I tried searching Java components, but I'm not getting the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

- A POJO is a Plain Old Java Object. A POJO is a straightforward type with no references to any particular frameworks. [Source](https://www.baeldung.com/java-pojo-class)
- A DTO is a Data Transfer Object. This is a pattern used to create objects that carry data between processes in order to reduce the number of methods calls. DTOs usually are also POJOs, as they don't have any business logic. [Source](https://www.baeldung.com/java-dto-pattern)
- An entity is a class that represents a concept, be it from real world or business logic. An example could be a class called User, which contains information about the user like its id, name and email.

If you want to know more about this terms in Java, I usually use [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/), as it contains a lot of information about Java and Spring framework.